# How to add if else statement in python along with function defination

Tags: python, if-statement

Sorry to bother i m new to coding just learning python. i just created some code by myself in python  no error shows. but why if else statement not executing. can someone help.

**code:**

```
def name(f_name, age):
    return f"Hi, {f_name} {age}"
    if age <= 18:
        print("You are Not eligeble for The post")
    else:
        print("you are eligeble for post")


person = name("Aditya", 17)
print(person)
```

Comment: you returned from function before executing if.

Answer (score 2):

On your line 2, you have used "return". It means below codes won't be executed. You should move the code line 2 to the end of function like

```py
def name(f_name, age):
    # this code has removed
    if age <= 18:
        print("You are Not eligeble for The post")
    else:
        print("you are eligeble for post")

    return f"Hi, {f_name} {age}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def name(f_name, age):
    if age <= 18:
        print("You are Not eligeble for The post")
    else:
        print("you are eligeble for post")
    return "Hi,", f_name, age

person = name("Aditya", 17)
print(person)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function, as soon as the function reaches a return statement, it will jump out of the function, because it already found what it was looking for, to return something. Because you returned your string at the very beginning, the program didn't get a chance to get the if/else statements.

```
def name(f_name, age):
    if age <= 18:
        print("You are Not eligeble for The post")
    else:
        print("you are eligeble for post")
    return f"Hi, {f_name} {age}"

person = name("Aditya", 17)
print(person)
```